# Conditional statistic summary dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, statistics, summary

I'm trying to get a table with the statistics (mean, var, standard deviation, among others) for `A` and `B` given `Y=1` and `Y=0.` For example:

Given this dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0,    0.91, np.NaN, 0.75,   np.NaN, 1], 
                   'B': [0.43, 1,    0.34,   np.NaN, 0,      0.64],
                   'Y': [1,    0,    1,      1,      0,      1]
                      })
```

I'm computing the statistics with:

```
for i in df:
    print(i)
    print("Mean Y1 " + " " + str(df[i][df["Y"]==1].mean()))
    print("Mean Y0 " + " " + str(df[i][df["Y"]==0].mean()))
    print("Var Y1 " + " " + str(np.var(df[i][df["Y"]==1])))
    print("Var Y0 " + " " + str(np.var(df[i][df["Y"]==0])))
```

However, I can't compare them, so I'm trying to create a table with the statistics like this:

```
stats = pd.DataFrame({'Column names': ['A', 'B', 'Y']
                   'Mean Y1': [A_mean_given_Y==1, B_mean_given_Y==1, Z], 
                   'Mean Y0': [A_mean_given_Y==0, B_mean_given_Y==0, Z],
                   'Var Y1': [A_var_given_Y==1,   B_var_given_Y==1,  Z],
                   'Var Y0': [A_var_given_Y==0,   B_var_given_Y==0,  Z] 
                  })

# NOTE: Z is any number, as its value doesn't matter.
```

However, a df doesn't accept the function .append as it's for lists. And convert a list of lists in a dataframe after computing the statistics, is very inefficient. So, any idea how can I create the stats dataframe with a loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did in this way at the end given its flexibility (you are not constrained by the agg function for example, you can put any function in the table just adding it in the loop):

```
 df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0,    0.91, np.NaN, 0.75,   np.NaN, 1], 
                   'B': [0.43, 1,    0.34,   np.NaN, 0,      0.64],
                   'Y': [1,    0,    1,      1,      0,      1]
                      })   
stats = []
for i in df:
    new_row = [
        i,
        df[i][df["Y"]==1].mean(),
        df[i][df["Y"]==0].mean(),
        np.nanvar(df[i][df["Y"]==1]),
        np.nanvar(df[i][df["Y"]==0]),
    ]
    stats.append(new_row)

col_stats= ['Variable', 'Mean Y=1', 'Mean Y=0', 'Var Y=1', 'Var Y=0']
stats = pd.DataFrame(stats, columns=col_stats)
stats
```

Answer (score 1):

I think need first [`DataFrameGroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) by list of functions for aggregate and then flatten `MultiIndex`, also if need reshape add [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) or [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df1 = df.groupby('Y').agg(['mean','var'])
df1.columns = df1.columns.map('_'.join)
print (df1)
     A_mean     A_var  B_mean   B_var
Y                                    
0  0.910000       NaN    0.50  0.5000
1  0.583333  0.270833    0.47  0.0237
```

Or:

```
df1 = df.groupby('Y').agg(['mean','var']).stack().sort_index(level=1)
df1.index = ['{}_{}'.format(j, i) for i, j in df1.index]
print (df1)
               A       B
mean_0  0.910000  0.5000
mean_1  0.583333  0.4700
var_0        NaN  0.5000
var_1   0.270833  0.0237
```

Or:

```
df1 = df.groupby('Y').agg(['mean','var']).stack(0).unstack(0)
df1.columns = ['{}_{}'.format(i,j) for i, j in df1.columns]
print (df1)
   mean_0    mean_1  var_0     var_1
A    0.91  0.583333    NaN  0.270833
B    0.50  0.470000    0.5  0.023700
```

For `Series` in output:

```
s = df.groupby('Y').agg(['mean','var']).unstack()
s.index = ['{}_{}_{}'.format(i,j,k) for i, j,k in s.index]
print (s)
A_mean_0    0.910000
A_mean_1    0.583333
A_var_0          NaN
A_var_1     0.270833
B_mean_0    0.500000
B_mean_1    0.470000
B_var_0     0.500000
B_var_1     0.023700
dtype: float64
```